# anchor tag link is changing the URL or not changing the state Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am having an element link this in my code. Order Status

and the state like this in router.js

```
.state('order_status', {
        url: '/order_status',
        views: {
            'slot1': {
                templateUrl: 'app/modules/search/search.html',
                controller: 'SearchController',
                controllerAs: 'srchCtrl'
            },
            'slot2': {
                templateUrl: 'app/modules/order_status/order_status.html',
                controller: 'OrderStatusController',
                controllerAs: 'orderStatusCntrl'
            }
        },
        operatorLogin: true
    })
```

but when I click on that link nothing is happening. Can I know what might be reason or am I doing something wrong?

```
<div class="container">
<div data-ui-view="slot1" class="slot-1 row"></div>
<div data-ui-view="slot2" class="slot-2 row"></div>
<div data-ui-view="slot3" class="slot-3 row"></div>
<div data-ui-view="slot4" class="slot-4 row"></div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you have `<div ui-view="slot1"></div><div ui-view="slot2"></div>` in the `<body>`?

Comment: give your html code ? the problem might be there

Comment: I have those in my html and I have attached html code also